# Adding AJAX to Rails 4 Like/Unlike Button with Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Wondering if I could get some help with trying to add ajax to my like/unlike feature. Everything works fine right now (without ajax), but I would like to add in ajax and hence avoid page reloading whenever the like/unlike is clicked. I've been racking my brain for many hours, read up on all the related questions regarding this on stackoverflow and anywhere else in general, to no avail. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a Project, User, Likes models (among others) and the user has ability to click like/ unlike (I used link_to helper with a partial) the particular project and the counter shows overall likes.

views/projects/_like_button.html.erb

```
<div id="like_or_unlike">
<% if @project.liked?(current_user) %>
  <% like = @project.likes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first %>
  <div class="unlike_button">
  <%= link_to "UnLike", like_path(id: like.id, project_id: @project.id), :method => :delete %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Like", project_likes_path(@project), :remote => true, :method => :post %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

controllers/likes_controller.rb

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    Like.create(:project => @project, :user => current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project), :notice => "Liked!" }
      format.js { render '/projects/show.js.erb' }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    like = Like.find(params[:id])
    like.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project), :notice => "Unliked!" }
      format.js { render '/projects/show.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

views/projects/show.js.erb

```
$('#like_or_unlike').html('<%= j(render partial: '/projects/like_button') %>');
$('.likeit').html('<%= @project.likes.count %>');
```

I know the above show.js.erb is incorrect and as well, I'm totally confused as to what is should be called or what should be pointing to it. As well, I know I'm possibly missing a  ???.js file to handle the ajax request. Again, any help or direction on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Will just mention that if statements in the view like this `<% if @project.liked?(current_user) %>` are not a good practice. You will notice that this simple if statement will make a database query every time you load the page. Better store the initially requested likes array into JS and check the existance with JS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and good point, will definitely refactor once I get this version working first.

Comment: Also just going to mention this: I think using pure JS and ajax in Rails is very clunky and leads to complicated code. If you plan to be making something big out of your application, then consider using AngularJs. Here are some good examples on how to implement it: https://github.com/mkwiatkowski/todo-rails4-angularjs, https://github.com/sectore/CafeTownsend-Angular-Rails. But if it's just going to be an application you use for learning, then it might be an overkill to use it. You will have to choose your self.

Comment: Yes, totally agree and going forward I hope to move in the Angular JS direction. This is just a project for learning. I knew nothing about ruby/rails or JS/AJAX/jQuery three months ago, but I'm learning more and more everyday. Thanks for the tip and link, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redirecting the request before reaching the `respond_to` block. Anything that comes after `redirect_to` will not run. You are also missing an `end` statement to close your `respond_to` block. I'm assuming you only want to redirect the user on an HTML request. If so change the ending of your `create` and `destroy` methods to this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to project_path(project), :notice => "Some message" }
  format.js { render 'your_javascript_file' }
end
```

Now you'll need some Javascript files to actually change the web page. Whether you'll need one or two Javascript files is up to you and how you want each link to behave after it's clicked.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much, this really helps! I totally missed how the `redirect_to` messed things up. I actually had the correct `end` statements, but somehow missed that when pasted my code. I have updated my code above to reflect this. I think I'm almost there. Right now, everything works EXCEPT of course the javascript part. I'm able to click like button, but does not update until I reload the page because my javascript is still messed up. I apologize, but I'm very new to ajax (and javascript in general), so still trying to figure out the code for `show.js.erb` and any more help appreciated!

Comment: Yea mate, it honestly sounds like you need to read the Rails guide some more. Group the HTML you want to dynamically change via AJAX into a container. Probably change the `p` tag you have encapsulating the like/unlike buttons into a `div` tag. Assign it an id or a class, then use the Javascript file called to replace the current content with a new one. The opening `div` tag would look something like `<div id="like_or_unlike">` while the jQuery would be, `$('#like_or_unlike').html('<%= render partial: 'like_button' %>');`.

Comment: Hey thanks so much again! Incorporated your input and edited code above. Also added another line in `views/projects/show.js.erb` to render the likes count and realized I was missing  `@ ` in  `project` in the `controllers/likes_controller.rb`. Working great now, thanks again for your help!!!